# how to make field required in mongodb while inserting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I am using `nestjs` + `mongodb` with `typeorm` .I want to add validation that on `name` field.`name` field should be  `required` .so it will give error if I am trying to add `blank string` in mongodb. but it is not giving me error .it added blank string in mongodb why ?

I make entity

```
export class BootcampEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @ObjectIdColumn() id: ObjectID;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Column('text',{nullable: false})
  name:string;
```

like this

in controller or repository I am saving like this

```
async createBootcamp(
    createBootcampDto: CreateBootcampDto,
  ): Promise<BootcampEntity> {
    const { name, description } = createBootcampDto;

    const camp = new BootcampEntity();
    camp.name = "";
  //  camp.description = description;

    try {
      await camp.save();
    } catch (error) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
```

`camp.name = "";` It add hard coded `blank string`.it should give database error .but not giving any error.

i already used `{nullable: false}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing [validateOrReject method](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#usage)

```js
import {validateOrReject} from "class-validator";

async createBootcamp(createBootcampDto: CreateBootcampDto): Promise<BootcampEntity> {
    const { name, description } = createBootcampDto;

    const camp = new BootcampEntity();
    camp.name = "";

    const errors = await validateOrReject(camp);

    try {
      await camp.save();
    } catch (error) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to place it before `save` method you can use [BeforeInsert hook](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/listeners-and-subscribers)

```js
class BootcampEntity {

  ...

  @BeforeInsert()
  async validate() {
    await validateOrReject(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please answer one more question

Comment: can you please look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099379/how-to-define-location-in-an-entity-using-mongodb